# Deleting "broken windows" on PMSE

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

We have a number of old questions that are closed, and that have no answers or links to duplicate questions. In other words, they are broken windows, rather than signposts to on-topic content.

I'm trying to clean up some of these questions with delete votes. I'm currently using this search:

```
is:question closed:1 migrated:0 answers:0 duplicate:0
```

and voting to delete questions that:

1. Are at least a month old, implying that the OP isn't planning to clean up the closed question.
2. Have no upvoted answers.
3. Are not marked as duplicates with signpost links.
4. Have no links to related questions/answers within PMSE.
5. Have not been migrated elsewhere.

If you have vote-to-delete privileges, please help me clean up some of these broken windows. If you don't have close votes, please consider flagging such posts for moderator attention.

Finally, if you think I'm violating some "broken windows are cool" code of chivalry, don't hesitate to comment or answer below.

Comment: Totally agree. I've also deleted a couple of questions that I considered totally 'unusable', following the same patterns you mentioned above.